# Extra fields Vs. float numbers

Tags: custom-field

Well, I am trying to develop a simple web system that uses Joomla CMS.

The project is simple and becomes from a thought of working with Joomla categories, subcategories, articles and extra fields like database, tables, table line and table columns respectively.

For data input, I plan to use custom frontend forms for articles or ChronoForms component. For views, I plan to use articles with the help of Sourcerer plugin.

The current issue that I face is that Joomla's extra fields is not designed for using float numbers, the reason of this question: how can I use extra fields to work with float numbers? I will work mainly with currency values.

I thought about three solutions, but I had no success:

1. Using integer type, I put 0 for start and a great number for end, for example 1000000000 measuring units of the currency. I tried to use step 0.01 as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550071/joomla-float-form-field recommended, but that value was rejected.
2. I tried to use then the same range of integer but considering the value as a cent of the currency, with step 1. But on frontend is opens a listbox where I have to choose one option - I cannot write my own number. It is awful.
3. Using a text field, I can work with numbers on correct form, but it does not filter only numbers and the "." character (user can input invalid numbers).

Any help to use float numbers on text field in Joomla with correct validation to do not develop it apart?

Comment: you can use a text field and set its filter as float.

Comment: Mmm... Well, I forgot to include above that my language is PT-BR and I think there is a language issue about it: after "inteiro" filter, that means "integer", there is a "posição" filter, that means "position", that let you think that is is related to ordinal integer values, but it is really the float filter with wrong name on my language :( I searched about extra field filters on Joomla site and did not found any reference about a native float filter, so now I am happy to found it. Thanks (if you transform your comment as an answer, I mark it as the accepted one).

Comment: You can post an answer with your final solution and accept it as answer and can even get votes for it. So, go ahead if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FFrewin said, you can use text field and select float filter.

The PT-BR language actually has a language issue about that - I will report to developers.